# property.GetValue(this, null) leads to "Object does not match target type"

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms

I have a database class like this

```
class Database
    {
        [Browsable(false)]
        public long Session { get; set; }
        public string Förnamn { get; set; }
        public string Efternamn { get; set; }
        public string Mail { get; set; }   
    }
```

A DataGridView uses BindingList as it's datasource and I retrieve the selected row of a gridview as a database class instance like this:

```
Database currentObject = (Database)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
```

Now I'm trying to loop through the properties of "currentObject" like this:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo property in currentObject.GetType().GetProperties())
        {         
            var name = property.Name;
            object obj = property.GetValue(this, null);    
        }
```

But on line `object obj = property.GetValue(this, null);` it crashes and I get:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Object does not match target type.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You'll have to change this line from

```
 object obj = property.GetValue(this, null);
```

to

```
object obj = property.GetValue(currentObject, null);
```

First parameter of `GetValue` requires target instance to get the value. so when you say `this` runtime throws exception saying that no such property exist in `this`.

Comment: I know, had to wait 10 minutes :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, I have a similar situation, I have 2 classses with ReferenceTypes inside them, but my GetValue() works for the first time and fails second time. Can you please help

Comment: @CSharped what do you mean by failed? Failed in what way, any exception? I suggest you to ask the new question with the code which fails. You may link it here if you want me to look at it. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
foreach (PropertyInfo property in currentObject.GetType().GetProperties())
{         
    var name = property.Name;
    object obj = property.GetValue(currentObject, null);    
}
```